# How to train a neural network model with bert embeddings instead of static embeddings like glove/fasttext?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I am looking for some heads up to train a conventional neural network model with bert embeddings that are generated dynamically (BERT contextualized embeddings which generates different embeddings for the same word which when comes under different context).

In normal neural network model, we would initialize the model with glove or fasttext embeddings like,

```py
import torch.nn as nn 

embed = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, vector_size)

embed.weight.data.copy_(some_variable_containing_vectors)
```

Instead of copying static vectors like this and use it for training, I want to pass every input to a BERT model and generate embedding for the words on the fly, and feed them to the model for training.

So should I work on changing the forward function in the model for incorporating those embeddings?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Pytorch. You can use https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT which is the most popular BERT implementation for Pytorch (it is also a pip package!). Here I'm just going to outline how to use it properly.

For this particular problem there are 2 approaches - where you obviously cannot use the `Embedding` layer:

1. You can incorporate generating BERT embeddings into your data preprocessing pipeline. You will need to use BERT's own tokenizer and word-to-ids dictionary. The repo's [README](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT) has examples on preprocessing.

You can write a loop for generating BERT tokens for strings like this (assuming - because BERT consumes a lot of GPU memory):

(Note: to be more proper you should also add attention masks - which are LongTensor of 1 & 0 masking the sentence lengths)

```
import torch
from pytorch_pretrained_bert import BertTokenizer, BertModel

batch_size = 32
X_train, y_train = samples_from_file('train.csv') # Put your own data loading function here
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
X_train = [tokenizer.tokenize('[CLS] ' + sent + ' [SEP]') for sent in X_train] # Appending [CLS] and [SEP] tokens - this probably can be done in a cleaner way
bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
bert_model = bert_model.cuda()

X_train_tokens = [tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(sent) for sent in X_train]
results = torch.zeros((len(X_test_tokens), bert_model.config.hidden_size)).long()
with torch.no_grad():
    for stidx in range(0, len(X_test_tokens), batch_size):
        X = X_test_tokens[stidx:stidx + batch_size]
        X = torch.LongTensor(X).cuda()
        _, pooled_output = bert_model(X)
        results[stidx:stidx + batch_size,:] = pooled_output.cpu()
```

After which you obtain the `results` tensor which contains the calculated embeddings, where you can use it as an input to your model.

The full (and more proper) code for this is provided [here](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT/blob/master/examples/extract_features.py)

This method has the advantage of not having to re-calculate these embeddings every epoch.

With this method, e.g for classification your model should only consist of a `Linear(bert_model.config.hidden_size, num_labels)` layer, inputs to the model should be the `results` tensor in the above code

2. Second, and arguably cleaner method: If you check out the [repo](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT/blob/master/pytorch_pretrained_bert/modeling.py), you can find there is wrappers for various tasks (e.g `BertForSequenceClassification`). It should also be easy to implement your custom classes that inherits from `BertPretrainedModel` and utilizes the various Bert classes from the repo.

For example, you can use:

```
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', labels=num_labels) # Where num_labels is the number of labels you need to classify.
```

After which you can continue with the preprocessing, up until generating token ids. Then you can train the entire model (but with a low learning rate e.g Adam 3e-5 for `batch_size` = 32)

With this you can fine-tune BERT's embeddings itself, or use techniques like freezing BERT for a few epochs to train the classifier only, then unfreeze to fine-tune etc. But it is also more computationally expensive.

An example for this is also provided in the [repo](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT/blob/master/examples/run_classifier.py)

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the detailed explanation! @Sloth. I have already used this repo, here as you mentioned, when using the tokenized text for generating embeddings, it will lose the contextual details. Also I suggest you to view this [repo](https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service) which gives embeddings for sentences and for their tokens instantaneously (takes time with increased text length).

Comment: Also regarding the set of already available tasks, I agree that is a better way of doing those tasks particularly. But I am looking to solve a sentence similarity problem, for which I have a model which takes glove vectors as input for training, also this is while initialization of the model, but in the case of BERT, to maintain the context of the text the embedding has to be generated on the fly for the sentences and has to be fed. Which is what I was looking for ;)

Comment: @ArjunSankarlal Perhaps I'm missing something here but somehow I think you might have misunderstood, but my answer is about generating embeddings on the fly. It does take the entire sentence into account when calculating embeddings. So tokenizing & converting tokens into id is just to feed it into the Bert model's embedding layer. It then goes through the entire model and pooled to generate a fixed, `1 x hidden_size` embedding for the entire sentence (it's not `sentence_length x hidden_size` mind you). The repo you linked does nothing more than the code I explained in terms of processing.

Comment: @ArjunSankarlal for a sentence similarity problem, you might want to look at the `NextSentencePrediction` task also - it can be easily reframed as sentence similarity depending on the dataset. If you want to calculate raw similarity score between sentence embeddings however, I would think a model trained on NLI (such as Facebook InferSent/XLM) might do better.

Comment: Is there a similar repo in tf? I wasn't able to find any, for bert embeddings layer to be used in word sense disambiguation

Comment: @ElSheikh the repo I mentioned was renamed to https://github.com/huggingface/transformers and now also supports tensorflow

Comment: @luungoc2005 thank you, but this one requires TF2.0 and I am working with TF1.12 (it is a hard constraint to work with TF 1.14), however can you please let me know if there is any special preprocessing except adding [CLS] to the beginning of the sentence and [SEP] at the end for Word Sense Disambiguation

Comment: @ElSheikh the original BERT repo https://github.com/google-research/bert is in 1.x tensorflow. BERT is also available on tensorflow hub (so e.g you can use it with an estimator). If strictly for Word Sense Disambiguation, I wouldn't be sure that the resulting BERT embeddings will correspond to the respective words - for downstream tasks you're supposed to only take the vector at the [CLS] token, and vanilla BERT has a NSP objective which diverges from this.
If it's not working out, you can also consider using ELMO or CoVe (they are older but they are made for the task)

Comment: @luungoc2005 I already used GloVe and ElMo but not CoVe (will try using it) But cant i fine-tune BERT over my dataset? (correct me, if I'm wrong)

Comment: and if you can @luungoc2005 send me an article to tell the differences between cove and glove? I am searching about the differences

Comment: @ElSheikh yes you can fine-tune BERT, it's just not guaranteed to be the most effective/efficient for the task. You might also try RoBERTa which doesn't use the NSP objective at all

If you already used glove and elmo, cove is something of a middle ground. glove is static vectors, cove is computed (ala elmo) - but you're actually supposed to concatenate the glove and cove vectors together. Main difference between elmo and cove would be cove is word-level while elmo utilizes character-level features, and elmo is trained on more downstream tasks, while cove is merely trained on translation.

Comment: I will try to implement what you said, thanks a lot for your advice